# Mediawiki database backups growing and shrinking randomly?

Tags: mysql, database, backup, mediawiki

I have a backup script that uses mysqldump to dump a Mediawiki database, then archives it with gzip. It seems to be working okay, but I am curious why the size of the archives appear to grow and shrink at random. It's not a very active site, so large amounts of data aren't being added or deleted on the daily.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  91M Mar 27 11:46 wiki_data_20220325.sql.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  93M Mar 27 11:46 wiki_data_20220326.sql.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  92M Mar 27 11:56 wiki_data_20220327.sql.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 110M Mar 28 03:15 wiki_data_20220328.sql.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  99M Mar 29 03:15 wiki_data_20220329.sql.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 103M Mar 30 03:15 wiki_data_20220330.sql.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 107M Mar 31 03:15 wiki_data_20220331.sql.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  78M Mar 27 11:47 wiki_html_20220320.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 173M Mar 27 11:47 wiki_xml_20220321.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 173M Mar 27 11:47 wiki_xml_20220322.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 173M Mar 27 11:47 wiki_xml_20220323.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 173M Mar 27 11:47 wiki_xml_20220324.xml
```

The size difference persists after extracting the archives.

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 280M Mar 31 10:27 wiki0328.sql
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 110M Mar 31 10:26 wiki0328.sql.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 267M Mar 31 10:27 wiki0329.sql
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  99M Mar 31 10:26 wiki0329.sql.gz
```

It's not necessarily a problem, but I am curious. Is this common / normal behavior for databases dumped from complex software like Mediawiki?

Here's the relevant chunk of the backup script, in case it matters...

```
echo "## Set ReadOnly on"
echo "\$wgReadOnly = 'Dumping Database, Access will be restored shortly';" >> $localSet

echo "## Dumping XML..." 
php $dumpXML --full --quiet > $saveLoc/"wiki_xml_"$(date +%Y%m%d)".xml"

echo "## Dumping database..."
mysqldump my_wiki | gzip -f > $saveLoc/"wiki_data_"$(date +%Y%m%d)".sql.gz"

echo "## Set ReadOnly off"
tail -n 1 "$localSet" | wc -c | xargs -I {} truncate "$localSet" -s -{}
```

Thanks in advance for any info!

Comment: I am not an expert on mediawiki, but I notice there are a number of "cache" tables in the [database layout](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_layout). These could grow and shrink under normal usage.

Comment: There can be oscillations in backup size, but usually no more than 5%. Have you verified the smallest backups? Perhaps, they havr been aborted due to an error or network malfunction.

Comment: @BillKarwin Oh, that makes a lot of sense! I am somewhat new to mysql and navigating dbs, so some very basic knowledge escapes me. This is good to know. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexanderMashin This is what had me concerned. I haven't found any errors in the logs, but want to be sure I am not missing something, since the fluctuations are kinda big. Guess I need to do more experimenting.

Comment: To be sure about what is different, you could restore several backups of different sizes on a test instance of MySQL, and then use `SHOW TABLE STATUS` to get stats on the table sizes, estimated row counts, etc. and compare them (caveat: row counts from the table status are rough estimates, use `SELECT COUNT(*)` for a precise number).

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you again! I explored a few versions of the db using COUNT(*) and the major changes are all in the number of rows in the objectcache table. After reading some Mediawiki documentation, sounds like there is performance tuning I can do, and can even skip the objectcache table in backups, since it will be regenerated on the fly and is currently like 14k+ rows ;P Your advice has been extremely helpful because I had no clue where to even start solving this mystery. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of the comments above: the `objectcache` table in a Wordpress database varies in size, and this is normal. Therefore it will cause the database backup to vary in size. To minimize the size of the backup, some people omit the `objectcache` table from backups.